# SQL from EntityDataSource

Tags: entity-framework, entitydatasource, entity-sql

Is there an easy way to see SQL statements generated by EntityDataSource?

SQL Server profiling/tracing is not an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use NHProf a profiler for NHibernate and it is awesome. So I can surely say that you should try the [Entity Framework Profiler](http://efprof.com/)
I just checked and, as for NHProf, there is a free trial version.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion - but I was wondering if I could see SQL statement using existing VS 2010 tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast to `ObjectQuery` and call `ToTraceString`:

```
ObjectSet<User> objectSet = ObjectSet;
var query = (ObjectQuery)(objectSet.Where(u => u.LastName == "Doe").Select(u => u));
string trace = query.ToTraceString();
```

For tracing/caching you can try the [EF Caching and Tracing Provider Wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/ef-caching-with-jarek-kowalskis-provider).  I haven't had a chance to try it yet, but it's definitely on my to do list.

Comment: Looks interesting but is quite involved: I was wondering if there was something similar to this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework